# Data tables - Block sorting for column

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using Data Tables Jquery Plugin. Can anyone help me stopping the table from sorting the first and second columns?

I need the user to be able to click on the other columns and sort them, but when I do it, the first two columns also sort. **Can these values be locked and never sort? (I need them static)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For those of you looking to prevent sorting on columns but still allow them to sort when other columns are sorted:**

```
$('#table').dataTable({
        // Disable sorting on the first two columns
        "aoColumnDefs" : [ {
            'bSortable' : false,
            'aTargets' : [ 0,1 ]
        } ]
    });
```

Or alternatively you can target a class like so:

```
// Disable sorting based on class
"aoColumnDefs" : [ {
    "bSortable" : false,
    "aTargets" : [ "disableSort" ]
} ]
```

Apply the class to the table header not the row.

**For the OP, how to make the columns completely static in order to maintain some sort of ranking / index feature every time a column is clicked:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "fnDrawCallback": function ( oSettings ) {
            /* Need to redo the counters if filtered or sorted */
            if ( oSettings.bSorted || oSettings.bFiltered )
            {
                for ( var i=0, iLen=oSettings.aiDisplay.length ; i<iLen ; i++ )
                {
                    $('td:eq(0)', oSettings.aoData[ oSettings.aiDisplay[i] ].nTr ).html( i+1 );
                }
            }
        },
        "aoColumnDefs": [
            { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 0 ] }
        ],
        "aaSorting": [[ 1, 'asc' ]]
    } );
} );
```

Comment: I've done that, the header cell just stops behaving like a button, but when I sort the rest of the columns, these columns' cells are always affected. I need them not to move at all

Comment: What is the content of these two columns? Surely if you are sorting other columns, the data in these two columns is no longer applicable to the rows in the columns next to them?

Comment: Its a rank. I need all the columns to sort their values, but not this first and second columns, I don't want the rank to move at all

Comment: @GEspinha I see, I found this example which looks like what you want to do.. http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/counter_column.html - very sorry for misunderstanding your question first time round!

Comment: Yes, thats it! Thanks! ;)

Comment: @GEspinha Quite alright, have updated my answer to reflect your predicament!

Comment: @adaam Thank you bro. You help me a loth